# Solving Equations with radical Exponents

Tags: radicals

The question is $22= 2 + 5(5m - 11)^{1/2}$
 so to try to solve this I first subtracted 2 and than divided by 5.
than you get $4 = (5 m - 11)^{1/2}$

$$4 = \sqrt{5 m -11}$$

so$$16=  5m -11$$ 
     or 
$$16+11=5m$$
or 
$$27 = 5 m$$ This cannot work

Comment: So $m$ is a fraction, what is wrong with that? Also, is it a cube root or a square root?

Comment: Ohh i see what i did wrong thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice, for $\sqrt{5m-11}$ to be defined we have $$5m-11\ge0\iff m\color{blue}{\geq \frac{11}{5}}$$

Now, we have $$4=\sqrt{5m-11}$$
Squaring both the sides $$4^2=(5m-11)$$
$$5m=11+16=27$$ $$m=\color{red}{\frac{27}{5}}$$

The above $m=\color{red}{\frac{27}{5}}\geq \color{blue}{\frac{11}{5}}$ Hence, your answer is correct.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but i have a question..this may not resemble the original question but i have run into a problem recently the question is   $$ Y = \sqrt{-(x-3)}  + 4

Comment: @MathAsker You have already asked this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457364/what-is-the-vertex-of-this-radical-equation)